# Mysql - 3 tables query

Tags: mysql

I have these 3 tables:

```
Users
_________
Id - Int
UserName - Varchar

Table1
_________
id - Int
Titlte - Varchar

Table2
_________
Id - Int
Userid - Int
Table1id - Int
```

I want to run a query that will show all the records from Table1 that are NOT SHOWING UP IN TABLE2.

For example, if my userid is 5 and table2 have this record:
Userid - 5
Table1id - 3

It should show up rows 1,2,4,5.... etc from table1 and skip row 3.

How do i do that ?!
I think it can be done using Join but i'm not sure how to...

Please help me figure this out :)

Comment: You have to check for `JOIN`.

Comment: Hey, i know it can be done by join query, but how do i select all rows EXCEPT the ones that are showen on table2 under table1id ?

Comment: Can you create an sqlfiddle and show us the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use **nested** queries:

`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM Table2);`

Comment: Yessssssssss !!! This works amazing !!!! The solution for me would be:
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT table1id FROM Table2 where uid=5);

Thank you so much !
Is there a way to do it without spending so much resources from the db?

Comment: You could try `left join` on the 2 `id` columns and `select` `where` `Table2.userid is null`. Though I'm not sure the query plans will be different in this small case. Why do you think it's inefficient?

Comment: They will be different, as nested queries create temp table + 2 queries instead of one in difference to JOIN. I'm a little confused though what exactly OP wants to do, and nested query is simple for this purpose.

Comment: The mysql will go first to the second part of the query ? [(SELECT userid FROM Table2);] and only then will do the selection from table1? If so, i think it might be the right solution for me

Comment: Semantically, both will be equivalent. Also, both would be thrown off if for some inadvisable reason you had an actual `null` in an ID column, but that's a bad idea anyway. Feel free to compare the two and measure the performance; as @eithedog said, there might be some difference one way or the other.